SpaCy not recognizing NORP (nationality)
nlp= spacy.load(en_core_web_lg-3.7.1)

name = 'Las Palmas Mexican Restaurant & Bar'

doc = nlp(name)
    for token in doc:
        print(f"{token.text}  \t{token.ent_type_} \t{token.ent_iob_}")
    print('-----------------')

Las     ORG     B
Palmas      ORG     I
Mexican     ORG     I
Restaurant      ORG     I
&   ORG     I
Bar     ORG     I
-----------------

So, SpaCy is considering the whole thing as ORGanization. How can I make it understand that "Mexican" should be annotated also as  ORP? (nationality, religious, political). If I make the "Restaurant & Bar" lower-case, then it would. However, I prefer not to have to deal with making a rule about what I should make lower-case.
